# __block attribute on property declarations

Tags: objective-c, ios, gcc, llvm, llvm-gcc

I have to fix some existing code that builds just fine with LLVM (on iOS) so that it builds with llvm-gcc-4.2 too. I'm done with pretty much everything, except this pattern which is found at a few places:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) __block id myProperty;
```

I suspect the intent here is to allow access to the property from inside a block without retaining `self`. How can I remove the `__block` attribute, which gcc doesn't support here, but still achieve the same effect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need `__block` on properties... it's for stack allocated locals. In any case, just try it. if there are no errors you are fine.

Comment: From the Clang language spec: "In addition to the new Block type we also introduce a new storage qualifier, __block, **for local variables**" cf. http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-137/src/tools/clang/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'll suggest you've found a compiler bug, the declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) __block id myProperty;
```

is meaningless. The `__block` qualifier is used on local (stack allocated) variables so they are passed by reference to blocks, so they can be updated, and are usually[*] stored on the heap rather than the stack.

Therefore the qualifier `__block` has no meaning on a property declaration which is concerned with object instances, which are heap allocated at all times in Obj-C.

Just drop the `__block` from the property declarations - for every compiler.

[*] If a block is never copied to the heap a compiler may optimize __block variables and not move those to the heap either.

Answer (score 5):

just before you use the variable in a block, create a local pointer of type `__block`. Don't ever use `__block` in `@property` declarations.

EG: `TypeOfVariable __block *bock_pointer = self.property;`

`^{ inside the block use bock_pointer }`

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought, but I was wondering if there was another way to do it without touching the code that access said property (through another property attribute or gcc-specific `__attribute__()` maybe?)…

Comment: why just not using `self.property` in block?

Comment: why shouldn't you use a property in a block ? please explain or give a reference

Comment: accessing self in a block will retain self.